# ion refresher and fixed element

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[index behind other div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GaOl.png)

I drawed a red ligne where the index were

so i have a div which is fixed, but with my ion-refresher, 
the fixed div seem to go in absolute when i pull to refresh, i don't know how to fix this.

here my code

```css
    .alphabetItem {
        
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99999999;
        right: -4%;
        top : 200px;

    }
```

```html
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
            <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Tirer pour rafraîchir" refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Relâcher pour rafraîchir ...">
            </ion-refresher-content>
        </ion-refresher>
        
            <ion-col col-1 class="alphabetItem" scrollY="true" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                <div class="divLetter" *ngFor="let letter of alphabets" (click)="alphaScrollGoToList(letter)">
                    {{letter}}
                </div>
            </ion-col>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The `ion-refresher` is absolute anyway.

Comment: the ion-col is in position:fixed, but when i pull to refresh, it's like the ion col it's not fixed anymore

Comment: Hi, i'm stuck with the same issue too. Just saw on github that this is a still un-resolved matter. You can follow any possible progress here on [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13237)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ion-toolbar` component from Ionic Framework (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/).

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <!-- your fixed col -->
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    ...
    <!-- your content + refresher -->
    ...
</ion-content>
```

The `ion-refresher` is a really special component. No matter where you place it, it will be put at the top of the nearest `ion-content`. When you refresh, it will move down your scroll-content, where your fixed container is placed in. `<ion-toolbar>` should fix this problem.

Comment: i think that what i need, but now my fixed col is under other div, do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: i did it if you want to take a look

Comment: Did you remove your fixed attribute from your col?

Comment: when a remove this attribute or i when i put relative or absolute, either its hiden or its expand the header

Comment: Sure, it will expand the Header. Thats the desired behaviour.

Comment: what i want to do its to put an alphabetical index next to my contact list

Comment: Create a minimal working stackblitz or something like this.

Comment: i think i just gonna do delete the ion-refresher and create a button to refresh that will be the more simple way to resolve this

Comment: You could also try to create a nested `ion-content`, because the `ion-refresher` will always be placed at the top of its nearest parent `ion-content`

Comment: yeah i already tried that too but the pull to refresh only work to the ion-content with the ion refresh, wich is only on the top, with the height specified